# Check whether two types are equivalent

Tags: c#, unit-testing, codedom

For unit testing purposes, we would like to check whether the implementation of a class has changed. The classes to check mainly contains constants or static fields that are used across the application. Similar to language files.

Our idea is to get informed by a failing unit test when the implementation of such a class changes by comparing it with the last accepted version of the implementation. With this I mean this class is reviewed and accepted (or declined) manually by a team member when a change occurs.

Now, the actual question is: *How to compare two classes whether they are equivalent?*

**EDIT**

Two examples of such classes:

```
public class A
{
    private string _value;

    private A(string value)
    {
        _value = value;
    }

    public static readonly A Foo = new A("foo");
    public static readonly A Bar = new A("bar");
}


public static class B
{
    public const string Foo = "foo";
    public const string Bar = "bar";
}
```

Comment: why are you needing to compare changes based on last snapshot.. do you guys use any source control along with what I am guessing you are coding on VM's ?? also google search C#'s `IEquateable` You should implement the IEquatable<T> interface on your class, which will allow you to define your equality-logic. Actually, you should override the Equals method as well.

Comment: Sure we have. But I don't like the idea of integrating our source control into our unit tests to check a file for changes.

Comment: Do you care that the _code_ has not changed or that the _results_ of operations does not change?  Unit testing is not meant to detect code changes - it is meant to verify the results of operations against expectations.  Otherwise I'd suggest looking at protecting source control (alerts, security, etc.)

Comment: @DJKRAZE: In some cases we don't have instances but static classes.

Comment: Ideally you should write enough unit-tests that regardless of what have changed in implementation, your solution will continue to work.

Comment: sounds like you don't have any controls put in place where ever you are working.. TFS is a good tool to use for Different environments, builds, deployments, but it's not a test tool per-say.. get with someone who can setup youre Builds / Auto Builds it will make your life much easier..

Comment: perhaps you work in an environment with a bunch of renegade coders or so called coders whom don't understand the process of checking out code as well as checking in code and also sounds like you have a lot of headaches with others stepping on each others code.. take the lead and designate yourself as the lead developer and implement some hard standards..

Comment: @DJKRAZE: Your implications lead in the wrong direction. We don't have a problem with source control nor with understanding unit tests.

Comment: It makes no sense then what you are asking because if you are on a VM and you are doing snap shots and something goes wrong.. then why not just reload from the last working snap shot and or get latest on a particular source.. I think that your question has double meaning / implications..

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar: You are right. I just hoped there was a simpler way without duplication.

Comment: @DJKRAZE: With "snapshot" I don't mean a VM image or something like that. In fact we don't use VMs for developing. What I mean is a reviewed and accepted class implementation. And when it semantically changes it should fail a unit test. I will update my question.

Comment: thank you.. for agreeing to update the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Dio F - I'm not sure if this is what you're after. But you get check static properties via reflection for their value. I.E. if I'm to use your example:

```
var typeA = typeof(A);
var staticFieldsA = typeA.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var typeB = typeof(B);
var staticFieldsB = typeB.GetFields(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

var fooAField = staticFieldsA.Where(f => f.Name == "Foo").Single();
var fooBField = staticFieldsB.Where(f => f.Name == "Foo").Single();
var fooAValue = fooAField.GetValue(null);
var fooBValue = fooBField.GetValue(null);
// fail
Assert.AreEqual(fooAValue, fooBValue);
```

So regardless of implementation (const, public static field), you can check the value.

Comment: Although I was searching for a generic solution, I think your answer is the best you can get.